# Probability of a point within a certain range of a circle

Tags: probability, circles

Ok, so let's have a bit of fun here ..

I order a coffee from my local coffee shop and get a standard sized cup with lid.

The cup diameter is just under 3 inches in diameter, so we'll assume it's a full 3 inches here. The opening for drinking is only 1 inch "long" along the circumference.

[image: Drinking gap is 1 inch]

Each cup has a "fold" or "crease" somewhere on it when it's made.

[image: Cup's crease/fold]

Assuming the placement of the lid is completely fair and random ..

what's the odds that this crease ends up within the space of the drinking gap ?

Asked in another way: Given a Circle with diameter d (3 inch in this case) and an arc "AC" of length y (1 inch in this case), what is the odds that a random point on the circumference of the circle falls within the space of the arc AC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{AC}{2\pi r} = \frac{1}{3\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the circumference $c$ of the cup itself which is $\pi$ times the diameter.

This gives you $c = 3\pi$.

Then, since you have to have the 1 inch circumference opening in a specific spot on the cup the probability is :$$P={1\over 3\pi}$$

Answer (score 0):

If the crease is uniformly distributed, then it's simply the arc length over the circumference.  So, here it's $1/3\pi$.

Comment: huh .. that simple?  :)  thought it might be more complicated ... but ... yeah .. I can see that .. now ... Guess I'm trying to overthink ... again .. hehe :)